# Penrose Triangle and Umbilic Torus

Tags: general-topology, geometry, recreational-mathematics, homology-cohomology

Here are two images - one of each. It seems to me that they are the same object from the topological perspective, that one is just a smoothed-out version of the other. I think this because it is clear each has one side face, an enclosed body, triangular cross-sections etc. I guess I'm thinking loosely in terms of simplicial homology.

The Penrose Triangle

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Penrose-dreieck.svg/2000px-Penrose-dreieck.svg.png

The Umbilic Torus

http://scgp.stonybrook.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/UmbilicTorus-aerialview-web.jpg

To be fair, I cannot determine by just inspection if the Penrose triangle has a single edge or not - and if this would be enough to distinguish them topologically -  and it's not like I can go out and look at one to determine if it's really the same as the umbilic torus on campus.

Can anyone with a good visualization ability or maybe just more knowledge of homology help me determine the homology groups of the Penrose triangle? Or if not, is there perhaps some easier way to see if they are distinct?

Comment: To be completely clear, are you treating both these objects as solid 3-dimensional things or are you just interested in their 2-dimensional surfaces?  (It makes no difference: they are homeomorphic either way, but it's hard to discuss the problem if people are talking about different things.  My answer assumes you mean the 3d things, because Wikipedia claims the umbilic torus is 3d.)

Comment: They both look like the solid torus sharpened along the curve generated by $(1,3)$ under the usual cover $\mathbb R^2\to S^1\times S^1$, where $S^1\times S^1$ is the boundary of the solid torus.

Answer (score 1):

These are topologically both the same.  Indeed both are homeomorphic to a solid torus $S^1 \times D^2$, and hence are homotopy equivalent to a circle: you can imagine shrinking each cross-section down to a point.

The edges/faces thing is irrelevant from the point of view of topology.  For example the unit square $[0, 1]\times [0, 1]$ is homeomorphic to the disc $D^2$ despite having different numbers of corners/sides.

The Penrose triangle has two edges and a square cross-section.

Comment: Of courses the edges/faces alone are not of importance. But the homology is! For example, a triangle and a square have different numbers of edges, but their edges still bound a single face.

Comment: I don't see what the issue is.  They're homeomorphic and thus have the same homology as each other.  They're homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ so they have the same homology as that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make a brief contribution here because topology is not my forte. Nevertheless, I've developed a 3-D program that can create Möbioids (my terminology) of arbitrary planiform and number of twists. A *twist* consists of a single edge-to-edge turn. The figure on the left below depicts the umbilical torus with a triangular cross-section (deltoid, really) and a single twist. The figure on the right shows the Penrose triangle with a square cross-section and also a single twist. Each possesses a single surface.

Finally, the figure at the bottom shows a 3-D printing of the Penrose triangle. You can find more images and some animations at [A New Twist on Möbius](http://web.calstatela.edu/curvebank/moebius2/moebius2.htm).

[image: Umbilical torus and Penrose triangle]

[image: Penrose triangle 3-D print]

Comment: The link no longer works. A working one can be found here: http://old.nationalcurvebank.org//moebius2/moebius2.htm

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thanks for finding that and posting it.

Answer (score 0):

If we were to imagine cutting the surface of both shapes along the "edges" (where in the Penrose triangle we ignore the triangular bends), then the resulting surface is one continuous piece in both cases, but there will be a different number of half-twists (three for the triangle, one for the torus).  So in that regard, the two surfaces are not equivalent.

Comment: Do you think it's half twists? I guess an important question in my head is how far the twist goes - it determines whether or not there is one non-trivial edge or two. That is to say, if each twist were by a third, there would be two separate loops.

Comment: If I am an ant traveling on the surface of the object, how many complete turns do I make in the plane perpendicular to the direction of travel after I walk around the object once?

Comment: That's exactly the question I can't answer. I'm really bad at visualizing objects, so I have a really hard time thinking about those kinds of problems.

Comment: This is just not relevant though: topology cannot 'see' edges.  A torus with square cross section is homeomorphic to a torus with circular cross section.  A sphere (surface of a ball) is homeomorphic to a hollow cube.

Comment: @Jez  I am not talking about the topological properties, because **you** already answered that aspect of the question to my complete satisfaction.  Instead, I decided to try to interpret the original question's intent in a way that might make sense for someone who wanted to compare the "twistiness" of the two objects, and this is why I did not refer to any topological properties in my response.

Comment: @heropup: That's fair enough.  The original question seems confused about the relevance of edges and twists to, say, the homology, so I just wanted to emphasize the fact that they don't matter here.

Comment: It has to be a whole number of twists when the ant gets back to where it started, otherwise it would have somehow got inside the solid object.